# How to call function separately for each tab?

Tags: javascript

I want to call function for each tabs separately.
Like `function openCity(event, 'London')` and `function openCity(event, 'Paris')`

I am new in JavaScript and trying find a solution.
Here is my code and it works fine this way.How can I do it separately?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that    opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**hello!!**
I think you must setup two script files in the `head` tag to add Ajax functionality according to your article. just like this....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/ajax_openCity.js"> </script>
```

This script links link the AJAX function script commands to the current main page.so on this method must not make any changes to the php file.

I think you must refer to this book.. I recommend you this book named : **"Scriptin' with JavaScript and Ajax"** by **Charles Wyke-Smith.**

Answer (score 0):

Take the event out of the DOM and run it in the script : its better because it more efficient that way

```
  //execute scripts when DOM ready !
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
     var city;//define your city var

    //find all tab classes with queryselector
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks")

//loop though them and add click event
    for (const button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     city = this.innerHTML;//find city name better to use data-attribute

      openCity(event,city);

      })
    }


            });
```

keep your original open city function

remove onclick from all tabs .. add as many tabs as you like now